# Inserting Linux Kernel object (*.ko) by using Android NDK with an app

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an android device with support of USB host functionality. I have to load kernel module for the usb device connected to android system with the help of an app.

My app will start running after android device booted and waits for connection of usb device. If device connected it will load the .ko file from SD card.

This is just an idea. We know that, for computers we will use **insmod** command to load the kernel modules at run-time, as root user.

I want to know whether same thing **is possible with android app using android ndk** or not ?

If anybody know details about it please help me.

Comment: The Android USB host APIs are designed for apps to perform basic USB transfers within the userspace code of the app itself, rather than via a kernel module style driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a Kernel Module (*.ko) requires root. With that said, it's certainly possible but you must be running on a rooted device and your app itself must have root.

In a 'standard' scenario, no this is not possible.